# Combinatorial game played on a grid

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

Let the grid consist of r rows and k columns. Two players take turns moving a piece to an adjacent square (no diagonal moves). Once a square has been visited it cannot be visited again. The piece starts in the top left square, this square can therefore not be visited again. The loser is the player that does not have a legal move to make, as an example take a 2x1 grid, player 1 moves to the second square, and player 2 does not have a legal move, which means he loses. Is there a winning strategy, and what is it?

Obviously since draws are impossible, and this is a combinatorial game, there is a winning strategy. I firstly tried to imagine the game as an unary game of Nim with r*k piles. But this does not accurately represent the game. (Maybe something with bogus-nim, but I'm not very good at that). I secondly tried to play against an RNG, trying to mirror their moves, if they vertically I move horizontally within reason of course, but that did not yield anything.

Does anyone have a hint? I don't want to be bold and ask for a very leading hint, but at this point I don't know what to do.

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice (and delete the previous version)?

Comment: I felt like I wasn't clear enough in the previous question.

Comment: An interesting question! I was sure that this was covered somewhere in _Winning Ways_, but I don't see it in there anywhere offhand. It's perhaps worth noting that the game can be played on arbitrary graphs; the grid version just corresponds to a grid graph.

Comment: Hint: you can find a strategy where the move of the winning player is determined only by the piece position, no matter the rest of the board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first imagine $r\times k$ is uneven. This means that if we ignore the starting square we can divide the grid into pairs of two (look at the image). The first player always has to tread on the first square of a pair, whilst the second player always can tread on the second square of a pair. Since every pair is whole, i.e. there's no lone square (except for the starting one naturally), the second player will always do the last move. So the winning strategy for the second player is to always move to the same color that it is currently standing on.
[image: grid with pairs colored coordinated]
If the product is even then we don't ignore the first square. The starting square is therefore in a pair, which means that it is the first player that has the ability to move to the second square of a pair. Using a strategy-stealing argument it is clear that the first player has the winning strategy by using the same one that the second player had in the uneven case.

Comment: Brilliant observation! (+1)